# Trying to set WPF data triggers for greater than values with timespan

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set WPF values with greater-than values for `TimeSpan`s. I was able to do this with `int`s or `double`s but I get a slew of errors when I try to make a Converter with a `TimeSpan`.

My Converter:

```
class BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((TimeSpan)value) > 00:15:00;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("To Long On Lunch");
    }
}
```

My xaml:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <local:BreakRangeToBooleanConverter x:Key="breakconv"/>
  <local:BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime x:Key="breakconvtime"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>

<MultiDataTrigger>
  <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding time,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                   Converter={StaticResource breakconvtime}}"
               Value="Break"/>                                
  </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Indentation, this unknown mythological creature

Comment: Fixed. sorry for the poor grammer

Comment: _"a slew of errors"_ -- please be more specific. The code you posted isn't valid, so it's not clear what you want. You can review the `TimeSpan` documentation to see how to create `TimeSpan` values in code. For the code you show above, something like `return ((TimeSpan)value) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);` might work, but it's not really clear what your goal is, nor what specifically you're having trouble with. Please improve the question.

Comment: you fixed it. my failure for not understanding that in the documentation. if you copy that into an answer I'll mark you as having answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better way to write your converter:

```
class BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan _toCompare = new TimeSpan(00, 15, 00);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is TimeSpan))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return (TimeSpan)value > _toCompare;
    }      

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("To Long On Lunch");
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is a much better way to design the converter. I'm still new to programming so I'm trying to pick up on the way to do these things. still getting used to it. Thank you for the tip.